# Convert GeoDataframe to numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I am trying to create a binary mask of buildings in specific given areas of a shapefile. I have used geopandas.clip() function to create geodataframes of buildings in each specific area, but cannot figure out how to now convert this to an array of given size. Each image has to be a specific given resolution hence I have the size the array needs to be, and I know how to convert this array into the desired image, but I am completely stuck on this step of converting the geodataframe to the correct format.

Note: I know I can display the data using .plot() but this (as far as I know) doesn't give the control I need over the resolution and being a binary mask, I think I need a more robust method.

Any suggestions welcome, currently pretty lost.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. You get the best reponses if you provide an example of what you have tried, preferably something others can reproduce. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: are you trying to rasterize a vector layer?

Comment: That would do the trick, but I've been struggling to even do that.